# Nancy Register Modules After Application StartUp

Tags: c#, nancy

I am adding modules from external libraries after the application starts up, and I'd like to know if there is a way to register them that way. Currently I override the Modules variable in the bootstrapper file to get the module types from this external assembly and that works fine, but I am not sure how to register modules after this variable is called.

Comment: I'm playing around with this myself and I found that you don't need to create a bootstrapper as long as you can assure that the external library has been loaded into the current app domain. This may require "hard binding" or calling some kind of static method (doesn't matter what) in that external library before initializing Nancy. My test found all the modules from my external libraries without a custom bootstrapper.

Comment: Ahh good catch, I've been overriding the IEnumerable<ModuleRegistration> Modules getter for a while now, I guess I never tried just loading the assembly. I'll have to give this a try now.